# How can I show data using a div when clicking a table row

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a page with a table which contains tracks from a users.

When you click a row I want it to show the track details in a div. I have managed to display the details using *on-click* + java script function but it displays the last track details.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a#tracks").click(function () {
        $("div#track-info").toggle();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a#close-box").click(function () {
        $("div#track-info").hide();
    });
});
```

I want to display the track details by its *track_id*? How can I get that?

Comment: You need to show us the table and script you are using if you want us to help you with it.

Comment: It's also important for us to see a table example. And from where you get the data you want to show. Also note that IDs should be unique and note more with the same name per page.

Comment: Please edit your question with more content and not put them in the comments

Comment: <% @tracks.each_with_index do |track, a| %>
<a id="tracks" style="cursor:pointer">
<div class="col-md-9">
    <h5><%= track.title %></h5>
     <div><%= track.user ? track.user.Firstname.upcase : "" %>  </div>
    <div><%= track.subgenere %></div>
</div> 
</a> 
<% end %>

Comment: <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 navtopfix" id="track-info" style="display: none">
 <% @tracks.each_with_index do |track, a| %> 
  <div class="row navtopbg">
 <div class="genclose"><a style="cursor:pointer" id="close-box">X</a></div>
 <div><%= image_tag("sheisdevilicon.png")%></div>
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
 <div><%= track.title %></div>
 <div>
  MR.<%= track.user ? track.user.Firstname.upcase : "" %>
 </div>
 <div><%= track.subgenere %></div>
 <div><%= track.created_at.strftime "%Y/%m/%d" %></div>  
<% end %>  
</div>
</div>

Comment: Click on edit and put that in your question

Comment: Sorry spokey,, it's not edited right now, dont know the problem.. use commented data.. kindly help me through this..

Comment: Am new for this, Simply the question is I want to display Track details when i click on my Track index by onclick().how can i pass id="tracks_<% track.id %>"

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but it's hard to answer without seeing the table structure? Can you please show the generated table?

Answer (score 0):

Change all IDs to classes and try the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.row.navtopbg').hide();

    $(".tracks").click(function () {
        $('.track-info').show().find('.row.navtopbg:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').show();
    });

    $(".close-box").click(function () {
        $(".track-info, .row.navtopbg").hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: This code is works. But it shows last track_info only. how can i get the track_info of clicked track_id

Comment: @mohdazmath Please show the generate HTML and make a fiddle with it http://jsfiddle.net/